# Posting search value via html button

Tags: php, html

I am searching for a possibility to replace the lowre input text field with a button like: `<input type="button" class="button" name="search" value="Urban" onclick="">`.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form method="post" action="search.php" id="search_form">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>" class="search_sounds"/>
    <input type="submit" value="" class="submit" /> 
</form>
```

The whole script is supposed to search the sounds of a database:

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search']))
    {
        include('searchfunction.php');

        if(count($data) > 0)
        {
?>
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                    var description = ''; 
                    var myPlaylist = [ 
<?php
                        echo(implode(',', $data));
?>
             ]; 

                    $('#main').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, { 
                    autoPlay:false, 
                    description:description, }
                    );

                    }); 
                    </script>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
            echo ('No sounds found.');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: On what event do you want to replace the text input with a button?

Comment: I simply want to replace text input field with a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an `id` element to your button, like this (I removed the onclick="" code)

`<input type="button" class="button" name="search" value="Urban" id="search_button">`

Then use some simple jQuery:

```
$('#search_button').click(function() {
  $('#search_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: I used the suggested code but it seems to be not working. The form is submitted but the php code is not affected!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you were trying to replace the submit button with a different kind of clickable button like an image.
If I understand you now, you want to have a text field, but when the user submits the form, you want to change that text field to a button element instead of a text field?

Comment: No I simply want to have a button which when it is clicked calls the php search function.